# Eventhandler for multiple generated buttons C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have generated multiple buttons when I click on btnStart and I'd like to use booleans for each button to become true when it gets clicked so I can check the clicked buttons later on but I only know how to use the same event for every button

This is what I use to create the buttons (I left some unnecessary things out)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) //I use this to horizontally generate buttons
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) //vertically generate buttons
                {
                    Button btnNew = new Button();
                    btnNew.Name = "btnFlag" + i;
                    btnNew.Click += new EventHandler(btnNew_Click);
                    Controls.Add(btnNew);
                    aButtons.Add(btnNew); //this is a list I use to set random bgImages
                }
            }
```

Now when I click on btnNew it would do all the code set for the event btnNew_Click but I can't use btnFlag1_Click because it doesn't exist, does anyone know a way to create booleans for every buttons and set one to true when a specific button is being clicked

Like: when btnFlag1 gets clicked, turn boolean btn1 to true
and so on ..

Thank you in advance

Comment: Quick solution: use the `Button.Tag` property to store a boolean, or an index that indexes into a `bool[]`. Hint: The `sender` argument of the event handler gives you the button that was clicked.

Comment: Or even simpler, use a `Checkbox` with `Appearance` set to `Button` and you'll instantly have a `Checked` property that does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are looping in your for statement you are assigning same event to all your methods.But the sender paramater of your method contains the reference of the button which is calling the specific event.

you can bind all the buttons to same event

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                Button btnNew = new Button();
                btnNew.Name = "btnFlag" + i;
                btnNew.Click += new EventHandler(btnNew_Click);

            }
        }
```

Then inside the button click new event you can select your specific sender and perform specific actions

```
public void btnNew_Click(object sender, ButtonEventArgs e)
{
   Button b = sender as Button;
   if( b.Name == "btnFlag0" )
   {
     //logic for your 1st btn
   }

   //.... repeat the same logic for others

}
```

Comment: Well, are the functionalities behind the buttons completely different? Then the alternative to 20 ifs would be 20 methods, right?
Or, if the process launched by each of these buttons is inherently the same and the specific button is just the parameter of that process, then try to parse that parameter from button's name (or have it as the name directly) and use it in your code in that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sender` argument in the event handler, which in fact is the specific `Button` which was clicked:

```
private void btnNew_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;

    string name = btn.Name;
}
```